# RSelenium Open Method fails with error 10061

Tags: r

I'm trying to get RSelenium working for the first time. Here's my code:

```
library(RSelenium)
checkForServer()
RSelenium::startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
startServer()
remDr$open()
```

The return text (after the open method) is:

```
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
[[1]]
[1] "ï»¿<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\">\r\n<head>\r\n \r\n<title>Error Message</title>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />\r\n\r\n<style>\r\nbody {\r\n\t\r\n\tbackground:#e5eaf5 url(/Wbo-FD9B7ED9-215B-4626-9B9E-D453142D7B18/bg.gif) top left repeat-x ;\r\n\tmargin:0px 0px 0px 0px;\r\n\tfont-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\r\n\tmin-width:1000px;\r\n\tfont-size:12px;\r\n\tcolor:#000000;\r\n\tdirection:ltr;\r\n\t}\r\nimg {border:none}\r\n\r\n\r\n\t.main {\r\n\t\twidth:100%;\r\n\t\tbackground:url(/Wbo-FD9B7ED9-215B-4626-9B9E-D453142D7B18/topright.gif) top right no-repeat;\r\n\t\tmin-width:1000px;\r\n\t\tmin-height:400px;\r\n\t\tmargin-left:auto;\r\n\t\tmargin-right:auto;\r\n\t\ttext-align:left;\r\n\t}\r\n\t\r\n\t.logo {float:left;  height:103px; }\r\n\t.sidetext {float:right; width:182px; height:52px; background:url(/Wbo-FD9B7ED9-215B-4626-9B9E-D453142D7B18/sidetext.png) top left; border:1px solid #2a2e31; margin-right:20px; margin-top:20px; padding:4px; }\r\n\t.sidetextNone {visibility:hidden; }\r\n\t\r\n\t.whiteline {float:left; clear:both; font-size:20px; margin-left:47px; margin-top:17px; color:#ffffff; white-space:nowrap; }\r\n\t.bold {font-weight:bold;}\r\n\t\r\n\t.maintext {float:left; margin-top:20px; clear:both; color:#000; margin-left:47px;}\r\n\t\r\n\t.color1 {color:#677183;}\r\n\t\r\n\tul {margin-top:0; padding-left:15px; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;}\r\n\t\r\n\tul li {list-style-image:url(/Wbo-FD9B7ED9-215B-4626-9B9E-D453142D7B18/bullet.gif)}\r\n\tA {\r\n    FONT-WEIGHT: bold; COLOR: #005a80;\r\n}\r\nA:hover {\r\n    FONT-WEIGHT: bold;COLOR: #0d3372;\r\n}\r\n</style>\r\n  \r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n\t<div class=\"main\">\r\n        <div class=\"logo\"><img src=\"/Wbo-FD9B7ED9-215B-4626-9B9E-D453142D7B18/logo.png\" alt=\"ForeFront\" /></div>\r\n        <div class=\"whiteline\"><td id=L_10061_2><span class=\"bold\">Network Access Message:</span> The page cannot be displayed </td></div>\r\n    <div class=\"maintext\">\r\n    <td id=L_10061_3><span class=\"bold color1\">Explanation:</span> The Web server refused the connection.  </td><br />\r\n<br />\r\n\r\n<td id=L_10061_5><span class=\"bold color1\">Try the following:</span></td><br />\r\n\r\n<ul>\r\n<li><td id=L_10061_6><span class=\"bold\">Refresh page:</span> Search for the page again by clicking the Refresh button. The timeout could have occurred due to Internet congestion.   </td></li>\r\n<li><td id=L_10061_7><span class=\"bold\">Check spelling:</span> Check that the Web page address is spelled correctly. The address may have been mistyped.</td></li>\r\n<li><td id=L_10061_8><span class=\"bold\">Access from a link:</span> If there is a link to the page you are looking for, try accessing the page from that link. </td></li>\r\n<li><td id=L_10061_9><span class=\"bold\">Contact website:</span>You may want to contact the website administrator to make sure the Web page still exists. You can do this by using the e-mail address or phone number listed on the website home page.</td></li>\r\n</ul>\r\n<br />\r\n\r\n<td id=L_10061_10><span>If you are still not able to view the requested page, try contacting your administrator or Helpdesk.</span></td> <br />\r\n\r\n<br />\r\n<td id=L_10061_11><span class=\"bold color1\">Technical Information (for support personnel)</span></td><br />\r\n<ul>\r\n<li><td id=L_10061_12><span class=\"bold\">Error Code 10061:</span> Connection refused</td></li>\r\n<li><td id=L_10061_13><span class=\"bold\">Background:</span>The server you are attempting to access has refused the connection with the gateway. This usually results from trying to connect to a service that is inactive on the server.</td></li>\r\n<li><td id=L_10061_14><span class=\"bold\">Date:</span></td> 24/02/2015 3:45:09 AM [GMT]</li>\r\n<li><td id=L_10061_15><span class=\"bold\">Server:</span></td> MELDVTMG1.oceania.cshare.net </li>\r\n<li><td id=L_10061_16><span class=\"bold\">Source:</span> Remote server </td></li>\r\n</ul>\r\n    </div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
```

Extracting some of the pertinent text I gather that

- Error number 10061 occurred, with associated text:
- The server you are attempting to access has refused the connection with the gateway. This usually results from trying to connect to a service that is inactive on the server
- The server in question is MELDVTMG1.oceania.cshare.net

This is a server in my organisation. I'm running behind a firewall, using a proxy, but as I understand it Selenium doesn't need to go through the firewall, it's the browser that does that. I hope I'm right in saying this.

I've googled 'rselenium open method 10061' and various combinations with no luck.

I've also tried using phantomjs with the code:

```
require(RSelenium)
pJS <- phantom()
Sys.sleep(5) # give the binary a moment
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = 'phantomjs')
remDr$open()
```

I get the same error text returned. However if I run phantomjs directly form the command line with a command like `phantomjs test.js` where the `test.js` file is:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.news.com.au/', function(status) {
  console.log("Status: " + status);
  if(status === "success") {
    page.render('example.png');
    console.log('http://www.news.com.au/');
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

...then it return 'success', along with a snapshot of the site, which indicates to me that it can get through the firewall and that's not the problem.

Am I missing something obvious? Any pointers would be gratefully received.

I guess I should say why I'm trying to use RSelenium in case there are better approaches. Basically I want to go to a web page, fill in some drop downs and press a button which causes a file to be downloaded.

Versions installed are:

- phantomjs v2.0
- RSelenium v1.0
- RStudio v0.98.1083
- R v3.1.1 (64-bit)
- Windows 7 (64-bit)

Comment: Try using a different port: `RSelenium::startServer(args = c("-port 4567"))`. `remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4567L)`

Comment: Sadly that didn't work. I tried a few other ports as well with no luck.

Comment: I should have added that I got the same error.

Comment: When running the Selenium Server start with `RSelenium::startServer(invisible = FALSE)` and check the visible console for errors. It is likely your Selenium Server is not started.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me @jdharrison. I've done as you suggested but the console flashes up and disappears before I'm able to read it. I will try to manually start the Selenium Server from the command line.

Comment: This [link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-headless.html) says I don't need the Selenium Server if I'm using phantomjs. Is that correct or do I need to persist with getting the Selenium Server started?

Comment: It is likely that the ports you are trying to listen to Selenium Server/(phantomjs in webdriver mode) are blocked. The console flashing up and disappearing indicates Selenium Server was unable to start. Open a console navigate to where the Selenium Server binary is and try  to start it manually. This should reveal what is preventing it starting.

Comment: OK, here's where I'm at. I am going down the phantomjs path so I've tried starting it in webdriver mode with this command: `phantomjs --webdriver=4567`. The error returned is '[ERROR - 2015-02-25T23:10:34.571Z] GhostDriver - main.fail - {"line":85,"sourceU
RL":":/ghostdriver/main.js","stack":"\tat global code (:/ghostdriver/main.js:85:
56)"}

  :262 in error`.

Comment: At this point it would be best to post an issue at https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues or https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs or look at the Selenium Server forum as this is not an issue with R/RSelenium.